# Android 9 patch blurry?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, uiimageview, nine-patch

I created a 9 patch png via androids tools but it appears blurry on my 260 ppi device.

I resized my image in Photoshop down to 48 x 69 as 9patch drawer recommends images to be as small as possible, because it supports scaling up not down.

I saved my image transparently as a png, its basically a transparent rectangle with a stroke.

Loaded in 9 patch drawer, outlined the stretchable areas (TOP and LEFT)

Saved the image...

Loaded it into an image button... but the image is blurry?

I re did the whole process but without resizing in Photoshop, and instead resizing in android and now its clear and sharp..?

Why is this? I thought 9patch scaled up sharply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's see a shot of the image, but more than likely the problem is that 9 patch is intended to be used in situations where you want to replicate pixels. So you need a more or less uniform area of pixels that you're looking to stretch.

Answer (score 0):

It is vague but… Fid you check if you saved from photoshop in correct format. 3 RGB channels + alpha. Double check your outlining color. It should be black #000000 and alpha channel should be #ff.